# Comparing two values from different databases causes a failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've got a problem regarding a SQL Query from two different Databases. I am looking at two tables from `d1=[some database]` and `d2=[some other database]`.

When I use the following query everything works:

```
SELECT
t1.ZVNUMMER,
t1.BUCHUNGSTEXT,
t1.VERWENDUNGSZWECK7,
t2.No_,
t2.Address
FROM d1.sometable AS t1,
d2.someothertable AS t2
```

The result is a CROSS JOIN between the two tables. Obviously I need some restriction in form of a WHERE clause.

This should take the relationship betweent1.VERWENDUNGSZWECK7 and t2.Address into account.

So when I modify the query to:

```
SELECT
t1.ZVNUMMER,
t1.BUCHUNGSTEXT,
t1.VERWENDUNGSZWECK7,
t2.No_,
t2.Address
FROM d1.sometable AS t1,
d2.someothertable AS t2
WHERE t1.VERWENDUNSZWECK7 = t2.Address
```

then the whole query fails.

However, when I compare `t1.VERWENDUNGSZWECK7 = 'somestring' AND t2.Address = 'somestring'`, then everything works. Since I can't work with the hardcoded comparison, I need to fix the above mentioned statement.

I have the feeling that it fails, because I compare two strings from two different databases, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Anyways, any help would be highly appreciated.

Both Databases use MS SQL.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when it fails?

Comment: No error message whatsoever. Its a really f**** up system that I have to use, where I don't get any error messages. Its fun

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with your SQL, so the problem must be in `jobrouter` whatever that is, or some other part of the "system" you're using.

Comment: thanks a lot anyways

Comment: Can you check the collation of fields `VERWENDUNSZWECK7 ` and `Address`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query with a JOIN clause like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.ZVNUMMER,
    t1.BUCHUNGSTEXT,
    t1.VERWENDUNGSZWECK7,
    t2.No_,
    t2.Address
FROM d1.sometable AS t1
JOIN d2.someothertable AS t2
ON t1.VERWENDUNSZWECK7 = t2.Address
```

Comment: using jobrouter if that means anything to anyone